# How to uninstall Apache Flex 4.14

Tags: apache, apache-flex

I'm looking for an uninstaller to remove Apache Flex 4.14 SDK from my C:\Program Files\Apache Flex SDK 4.14.

I did not find any uninstaller as such or any option in Add or Remove Programs to remove it.

Can I directly delete the folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can just delete the folder.